# Content disappers after '&' character in the phone's default SMS

Tags: android, react-native, sms

I have a problem.

Message content after '&' character disappears when open using the phone's default SMS application. Here is message format:

```
xxxx
https://example.com/api/v1/ExecDynamicLink?param=abc&openExternalBrowser=1
yyyy
```

```
&openExternalBrowser=1
yyyy
```

is disappears. So I want to pass all content to SMS application. Here my code:

```
Linking.openURL(`sms:?body=${encodeURIComponent(message)}`);
```

Can someone give me a solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `&amp;`, this will show an '&'

Comment: The content is still lost

Comment: Does the parameter in `openURL` contain the "&" when debugging?

Comment: No. It's "%26amp%3B". I use `encodeURIComponent` function.

Comment: When you type: `param=abc&amp;openExternalBrowser=1` ?

Comment: Yes, it is. `param=abc&amp;openExternalBrowser=1`